# How to schedule a query and save the results in a different project?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm attempting to use the new UI to schedule a query in BigQuery. I'd like to save the results in a different project, however the option to change projects is grayed out.

Looked through the documentation, but didn't find any mention of this.

Comment: Did you tried the other way around, run the scheduled query in the destination project and query from the other project?

Comment: Good advice from @Pentium10. Also, there are a few ways to schedule BigQuery queries. I personally preferrer using `Cloud Scheduler + PubSub + Cloud Function`, because it decouples it from user accounts i.e. it forces you to use service account. Just some food for thought.

Comment: @Pentium10 in theory that's correct, however we have one project on flat-rate pricing so that's where we run everything, just like to not save the results there as it'll get messy quickly.

Comment: @GrahamPolley I'll check your method, though I know the admins at our office prefer we don't use service accounts for things like this.

Comment: You can try superQuery IDE, the scheduler there allow you to work cross projects

Comment: Eventually check out this guide https://gtech.run/a2rbr

Comment: @TamirKlein - You should be really suffixing comments like that with _"Disclaimer: I work for SuperQuery!"_ ;-)

Comment: Interesting that your admins would want you using personal auth for that. I've never come across and it's the norm for the opposite. For example, what if you/employees off-board and you need those scheduled queries to continue running?

Comment: @GrahamPolley You're generally correct but in this case I only need it for a few months of research

Comment: Understood, but a lot can happen in a few months ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably late for the party, but came here looking for a way to make a query in the project x and save it in project y. Both projects are in the same workspace and I have access to both.

Scheduled queries are quite handy for this purpose, but it wasn't clear if they would solve my situation.

Whenever I make a query in project x, let's say `SELECT * FROM x.orders` I can only save the results inside x. The [scheduled queries documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) says *"Queries can reference tables from different projects and different datasets. When configuring your scheduled query, you don't need to include the destination dataset in the table name. You specify the destination dataset separately."*

The trick is that, you can't save queries made in X into Y, **but, you can query X from Y.**

So if you like me are here because you thought scheduled queries wouldn't solve your problem, you can simply, add all the projects in the same workspace, and then query the origin table from the destination project (click on it and it will do the job).